# how to store multiple arrays and make array of pointers to them

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I don't have a lot of experience with pointers, but I want to try to make an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to a scanned string.
For example, you first input how many strings you want to scan (for example 5), and then I want to scan those strings and make an array of 5 pointers that point to those strings.

Because I didn't have a lot experience with something like this, I first tried it with normal arrays instead of strings, what I got is this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

int **array(int m, int n) {    
int i, j;
int **array = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    array[i]=malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d", &array[j][i]);
    printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", j, i, array[j][i]);
  }
}  
return array;
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
int m, n, *p, k;

scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

printf("m is %d and n is %d\n", m, n);

p=*array(m, n);



printf("the numbers are:\n");

for (k=0; k<m*n; k++) {
printf("%d\n", p[k]);
}


return 0;

}
```

But here it's already going wrong, and I don't know why... 
At the last printf, I always get wrong numbers, 0's and 17's... 
Can someone explain me why this is and what I'm doing wrong? I think it's something with the returning of the array but I'm not sure..

If someone could explain this to me it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the following:

```
// m = 3, n = 5
// array = ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptr5
//           |      |
//          3 ints  |
//                 3 ints ..

int **array(int m, int n) {    
  int i, j;
  int **array = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

  for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      array[i]=(int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
      scanf("%d", &array[j][i]);
      printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", j, i, array[j][i]);
    }
  }  
  return array;
}
```

In the above example (m=3, n=5) you allocated 5 pointers to integers and then tried to populate them by **allocating memory at each iteration in the inner-loop** (WRONG). If you allocate new memory at each iteration, you're gonna lose the pointer to the previously allocated memory and the data you stored!

Plus the indices seem to be wrong for the inner and outer loop, a correct version of your code is:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

// 3, 5
// array = ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptr5
//           |      |
//          3 ints  |
//                 3 ints ..

int **array(int m, int n) {    
  int i, j, index;
  int **array = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  index = 0;

  for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
    array[j]=(int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int)); // Allocate once per each j
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
      array[j][i] = index++;
      printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", j, i, array[j][i]);
    }
  }  
  return array;
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int m, n, **p, k, i, j;

  m = 3;
  n = 5;

  printf("m is %d and n is %d\n", m, n);

  p=array(m, n);



  printf("the numbers are:\n");

  for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
      printf("%d\n", p[j][i]);


  return 0;

}
```

And the above version is **STILL NOT CORRECT** : You need to free the allocated memory!

I'll leave that as an exercise.. hint: you CAN'T simply do "free(p);" :]

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it much better now.

Comment: Glad that I helped. I've been a newbie for a **long** time and I still don't consider myself out of that phase, so I'm quite good at spotting other people's doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this for loop? If you've the malloc inside the inner loop you're not creating a matrix because every time you override the same cells...

```
int i, j;
int **array = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    array[i]=malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d", &array[j][i]);
    printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", j, i, array[j][i]);
  }
}
```

It should be something like:

```
int i, j;
int **array = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    array[i]=malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I see it now a little bit more clear.I changed it now like this:

Comment: when I try what you suggested, I get a segmentation fault, so I tried it with first 1 for loop for the malloc, and then 2 loops from 0-m and from 0-n, and then I scan the numbers. But now I get the numbers almost right, but with a 17 between them.. Where could that 17 come from? I keep getting it.

Comment: On my pc your code with my changes works without problem... Which values are you using as m and n?

Comment: However you should change your main: p must be int**, so p=array(m,n) and you should use a double loop as in the array function to print the values

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

void *array(int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    int (*array)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int [m][n]));//m*n*sizeof(int)

    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &array[j][i]);
            printf("array[%d][%d] is scanned and has value %d\n", j, i, array[j][i]);
        }
    }  
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int m, n, *p, k;

    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("m is %d and n is %d\n", m, n);

    p=(int*)array(m, n);

    printf("the numbers are:\n");
    for (k=0; k<m*n; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", p[k]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **array(int m, int n) {
    int i;
    char **array = malloc(m*sizeof(char*));

    for (i=0; i<m; ++i) {
        array[i]  = malloc(n*sizeof(char));//Fixed length : like char array[m][n] (char *array[m])
        scanf("%s", array[i]);//!! There is no length constraints.
        printf("array[%d] is scanned and has value %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }  
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int m, n, k;
    char **p;

    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("m is %d and n is %d\n", m, n);

    p=array(m, n);

    printf("the string are:\n");
    for (k=0; k<m; ++k) {
        printf("%s\n", p[k]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I do this smart, but I usually allocate the pointer array and then allocate the whole memory chunk to the first item. Then I get continuous memory for the data. Like:

```
_array = (float**) malloc( n * sizeof ( float * ));
assert ( _array != NULL );

_array[0] = (float*) malloc( n * m * sizeof ( float ));
assert ( _array[0] != NULL );

for ( idx = 0; idx < n; idx++ )
    _array[ idx ] = _array[ 0 ] + idx * m;
```

(float instead of int in my case. And please don't comment on the return of `malloc` casting, nor on the silly user of `assert()`)